# Smart pointers in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, smart-pointers

Like it has been written [here](http://blog.qt.digia.com/2009/08/25/count-with-me-how-many-smart-pointer-classes-does-qt-have/) Qt up to now has 8 specilized smart pointer classes.
It looks like it is all you will ever need.
However, in order to use any of these smart pointers your class must be derived from QObject which is not always convenient.
Is there other implementations of smart pointers in Qt which work with arbitrary classes?

Comment: Actually, for most of those pointers you don't need to derive from QObject, I don't think.  There are some other things your classes would need to handle, or derive from some other Q-classes, for some of them.  AFAIK, only QPointer needs your class to be derived from QObject.  That having been said, they do require the ability to use Qt in your project.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Many Qt classes are derived from QObject, and while some of the built in smart pointer classes are related to QObject (or QSharedData), the [QSharedPointer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qsharedpointer.html#details) and [QScopedPointer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qscopedpointer.html#details) templates appear to allow pointers to anything.

More "modern" C++ (from C++11 onwards) has useful smart pointer types: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30143936/33987.

Beyond that, you'll find some [smart pointer templates](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/smart_ptr/smart_ptr.htm) in [Boost](http://www.boost.org/):

- [scoped_ptr](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/smart_ptr/scoped_ptr.htm) - Simple sole ownership of single objects. Noncopyable.
- [scoped_array](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/smart_ptr/scoped_array.htm) - Simple sole ownership of arrays. Noncopyable.
- [shared_ptr](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm) - Object ownership shared among multiple pointers.
- [shared_array](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_array.htm) - Array ownership shared among multiple pointers.
- [weak_ptr](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/smart_ptr/weak_ptr.htm) - Non-owning observers of an object owned by shared_ptr.
- [intrusive_ptr](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_40_0/libs/smart_ptr/intrusive_ptr.html) - Shared ownership of objects with an embedded reference count.

Comment: This is right. STL also has auto_ptr. The question is about QT.

Comment: Virtually everything in Qt using QObject as a base, so if you want something that works outside of that, Boost one place to go looking :)

Comment: Wow, i still use C++ like "C with classes" (thats C++ around 1990). That works, all this ugly unreadable smart pointers insaneness make me sick.

Comment: Yeah, automatic memory management, eew, disgusting. How can we trust a C++ application if it doesn't have memory leaks? ;)